# Fail to compile oneAPI examples

Tags: c++, intel-oneapi

I installed oneAPI tools and tried to compile the example project, `vector-add`

```
make all
dpcpp -O2 -g -std=c++17 -o vector-add-buffers src/vector-add-buffers.cpp
In file included from src/vector-add-buffers.cpp:22:
In file included from /home/xxx/opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/2022.0.2/linux/bin-llvm/../include/sycl/CL/sycl.hpp:11:
In file included from /home/xxx/opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/2022.0.2/linux/bin-llvm/../include/sycl/CL/sycl/accessor.hpp:12:
In file included from /home/xxx/opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/2022.0.2/linux/bin-llvm/../include/sycl/CL/sycl/atomic.hpp:12:
In file included from /home/xxx/opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/2022.0.2/linux/bin-llvm/../include/sycl/CL/sycl/access/access.hpp:10:
In file included from /home/xxx/opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/2022.0.2/linux/bin-llvm/../include/sycl/CL/sycl/detail/common.hpp:116:
In file included from /home/xxx/opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/2022.0.2/linux/bin-llvm/../include/sycl/CL/sycl/exception.hpp:17:
In file included from /home/xxx/opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/2022.0.2/linux/bin-llvm/../include/sycl/CL/sycl/stl.hpp:13:
/home/xxx/opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/2022.0.2/linux/bin-llvm/../include/sycl/CL/sycl/bit_cast.hpp:33:22: error: no member named 'is_trivially_copyable' in namespace 'std'
  static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable<From>::value,
                ~~~~~^
/home/xxx/opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/2022.0.2/linux/bin-llvm/../include/sycl/CL/sycl/bit_cast.hpp:33:44: error: 'From' does not refer to a value
  static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable<From>::value,
                                           ^
```

I suspect it was caused by the old `cmake`, `pkg-config`, `make`, `gcc` and `g++`, but I don't have root access to the cluster. I tried to reinstall it with `conda`. It was not helping anyway.

Comment: `is_trivially_copyable` showed up in C++11. Make sure your compiler's not out partying with dinosaurs.

Comment: @user4581301 Thanks for the help. I was using `dpcpp` to compile the project, it was brand new. (`Intel(R) oneAPI DPC++/C++ Compiler 2022.0.0`) But the `g++` is very old (`g++ (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4)`), would that be a problem?

Comment: GCC 4.8.5 has slightly dodgy C++11 support. I would upgrade the compiler, but odds are good that if you add `-std=c++11` to the compiler command line you'll have success.

Comment: Mind you, I don't know what `From` is, so you might still have trouble with it.

Comment: In fact, the compiler command is `dpcpp -O2 -g -std=c++17 -o vector-add-buffers src/vector-add-buffers.cpp`, it should work with the C++11 keywords.

Comment: Good point. I should have looked closer. GCC 4.8.5 as no clue what C++17 is , so if GCC  is getting involved in any way, there should be a " WTF is this `-std=c++17` option?" error. The paths listed say that the compiler's looking at the correct Standard library. At this point I'd go looking for macros or similar disabling features.

Comment: Yeah, I tried to switch `dpcpp ` to `g++`, it complained about `-std=c++17`. But the brand new `dpcpp ` shall support `-std=c++17` option.

Answer (score 1):

In order to compile the vector-add sample code with dpcpp compiler, your gcc version should be atleast 7.3.0 or above.

For more information, please refer to the link below.

https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/system-requirements/intel-oneapi-dpcpp-system-requirements.html

Answer (score 0):

You can compiler [gcc](https://linuxhostsupport.com/blog/how-to-install-gcc-on-centos-7/) by yourself(it's easy) and use `export CXX=/path/gcc-9.2.0/bin/g++` and `export CC=/path/gcc-9.2.0/bin/gcc` to set compiler env for cmake.